# DVR cleint software for Ubuntu?

Tags: server, dhclient

My DVR is working for windows based Client software but I would like to use Ubuntu base client software to record the videos and images.

Can anyone suggest me the suitable software for DVR client ubuntu?

I tried these client Softwares in ubuntu and failed to get recording and images (I have analog cameras)

Zoneminder, Xeoma, Smarpss

I am using ubuntu 64 Bit OS.

Comment: What's your DVR server, and what protocols do it use?